# Adding DataTable expression result as a mutable column

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable containing two columns that I'd like to concatenate. I'm aware [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-expression-columns) can do this for evaluation, but if I want the result of that expression to then be the starting point for a further update (specifically, I want to update the results of the expression with the values held in another table), the expression column is read-only.

Alternatively, is there way to add a new column that uses the expression column as a join, and then save the target value from a second table into my original? I've tried doing this iteratively in the below code, which works, but feels like it would be better as a set-based operation if possible.

```
const string COL_NAME_SEGMENT1 = "Segment1";
const string COL_NAME_SEGMENT2 = "Segment2";
const string COL_NAME_COMBINATION = "Combination";
const string COL_NAME_RESULT = "Result";
const string COL_NAME_SOURCE_VALUE = "SourceValue";
const string COL_NAME_TARGET_VALUE = "TargetValue";

var dataTable = new DataTable("MutableDataset");
dataTable.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_SEGMENT1, typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_SEGMENT2, typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_COMBINATION, typeof(string), $"{COL_NAME_SEGMENT1}+'-'+{COL_NAME_SEGMENT2}");
dataTable.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_RESULT, typeof(string));
dataTable.Rows.Add("A", "1");
dataTable.Rows.Add("A", "2");
dataTable.Rows.Add("B", "1");
dataTable.Rows.Add("B", "2");

var lookup = new DataTable("LookupData");
lookup.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_SOURCE_VALUE);
lookup.Columns.Add(COL_NAME_TARGET_VALUE);
lookup.Rows.Add("A-1", "1000");
lookup.Rows.Add("B-1", "0800");
lookup.Rows.Add("A-2", "0700");
lookup.Rows.Add("B-2", "0500");

foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    //row[COL_NAME_COMBINATION] = lookup.Select($"{COL_NAME_SOURCE_VALUE} = '{row[COL_NAME_COMBINATION]}'")[0][COL_NAME_TARGET_VALUE]; //System.Data.ReadOnlyException Message = Column 'Combination' is read only.
    row[COL_NAME_RESULT] = lookup.Select($"{COL_NAME_SOURCE_VALUE} = '{row[COL_NAME_COMBINATION]}'")[0][COL_NAME_TARGET_VALUE]; //This works, but at the expense of a temporary/superfluous column. Also, can it be done set-based?
}

var consoleStream = new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput());
dataTable.WriteXml(consoleStream);
```

As the quick Console app shows, I've tried directly updating the expression column, and the exception is understandable, but I was hoping it might be possible to save the expression results to the column values or similar.